# How can I control individual HTML items in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to show a list of enable/disable buttons for a list of users. Each user should have the appropriate button, i.e. if a user is disabled, the button enable should be displayed, and vice versa. I have the flags "userEnableFlag" and "userDisableFlag" in the TypeScript file to control which button is to be displayed for each user.

The flags control all the buttons at once instead of controlling each button individually. So if the userEnableFlag is set to TRUE somewhere and theN set to FALSE later on, only the disable button will be displayed for every instance in the webpage.

```html
<clr-dg-action-overflow>
        <button class="action-item" *ngIf="userEnableFlag" (click)="enableSingle(item)">Enable</button>
        <button class="action-item" *ngIf="userDisableFlag" (click)="disableSingle(item)">Disable</button>
</clr-dg-action-overflow>
```

Here is a snippet from the TypeScript

```js
this.setupUserStreaming().subscribe((results: Array<UsersResponse>) => {
      // console.log(results);
      if (user.enabled) {
              this.userDisableFlag = true;
              this.userEnableFlag = false;
            } else {
              this.userDisableFlag = false;
              this.userEnableFlag = true;
            }
     });
}
```

I expect every button to be displayed individually based on the flag value for each instance individually.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another field to each user in your list, such as `isEnabled`.

So, every time you want to enable/disable a user, you'd simply pass the user to your method and modify its property.

Here's the idea translated into code:

```js
const users = [
    { id: 1, /* ... */ isEnabled: false },
    { id: 2, /* ... */ isEnabled: false },
    { id: 3, /* ... */ isEnabled: false },
];

enableSingle (user) {
    user.isEnabled = true;

    /* ... */
}

disableSingle (user) {
    user.isEnabled = false;

    /* ... */
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
    <!-- ... -->
    <clr-dg-action-overflow>
        <button class="action-item" *ngIf="!user.isEnabled" (click)="enableSingle(user)">Enable</button>
        <button class="action-item" *ngIf="user.isEnabled" (click)="disableSingle(user)">Disable</button>
    </clr-dg-action-overflow>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove that viariables and check the status of each record

for example assuming you have a property called `isEnabled` on each `item`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of users">

  <clr-dg-action-overflow>
        <button class="action-item" *ngIf="item.isEnabled === false" (click)="enableSingle(item)">Enable</button>
        <button class="action-item" *ngIf="item.isEnabled === false" (click)="disableSingle(item)">Disable</button>
  </clr-dg-action-overflow>

</div>
```

and in your code

```
enableSingle(item) {
  item.isEnabled = true;
}

disableSingle(item) {
  item.isEnabled = false;
}
```